# No "JavaEE" perspective even after installing Web,XML,... in "Eclipse-for Java Developers edition"

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-indigo

So the situation is like this ...I am having "Eclipse Indigo for Java Developers"....
and now i need to develop some web applications(dynamic web projects)..so i went to "Help" in eclipse menu :
Help > Install new software 
and downloaded the whole bundle "Web,XML,JavaEE and OSGi Enterprise Development"...
but after that too there is no JavaEE perspective in eclipse..only java perspective..

I have checked in "Other" section too of perspective..but unable to find it..
What am i doing wrong here ??

I am on windows 7 ,64 bit and running android-sdk/tools perfectly !!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a reason to stay on Indigo, you could just download and install the Juno version of "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads)

Keep your existing workspace (make a backup of it if you want). Install eclipse (unzip). Start eclipse and point it to your existing workspace.

If you installed plugins for eclipse Indigo, you will need to install them again for the Juno version.

Comment: Juno can import plugins from an existing eclipse folder.

Comment: but i have a lot of projects (around 40) open and they are simultaneously used by other machines too..i m a bit scared by the thought of upgrading as it might break the system !!
my question is why JavaEE is not showing in my eclipse ?